# file write using java applet

Tags: java, file, applet

```
public class filewrite {



public static void main(String ar[]){
  try{
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("database.txt")));
     BufferedWriter br2=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("database1.txt")));

     String st;
     while((st=br.readLine())!=null){

       br2.write(st+"\n");
      }
    }
   catch(IOException e){}        
   }
  }
```

no error or warning, but still it can't copy the data from "database.txt" to "database1.txt"

please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Applet` is part of web application. Think about, Where it will write the file?

Comment: Remember `Applet` resides on server but executes on client(browser).

Comment: Applets aren't allowed to write to files by default. If you want your applet to run without security restrictions, you need to sign your applet, which shows the user a security warning before it will run, and costs money (for the certificate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it to allow a privileged action. Using the AccessController. Try this:

```
public void start() {
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>(){
        @Override
        public Object run() {
            try{
              BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("database.txt")));
              BufferedWriter br2=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("database1.txt")));

              String st;
              while((st=br.readLine())!=null){
                String []str=st.split(";");
                br2.write(st+"\n");
              }
            }
            catch(IOException e){}        
                //catch your exceptions
            }
        }               
    });
}
```